# neo4j transaction logs not pruned

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to write a large set of nodes to neo4j Enterprise 3.3.3. The transaction logs grow until I run out of disk space.

I tried to set `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=20G size` to limit the transaction log file size. However, the transaction log files kept growing even though `debug.log` contained entries saying that log pruning was started and completed.

I tried to also set `dbms.checkpoint=volumetric` to force regular checking of logs for pruning as described here: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/checkpointing-and-log-pruning-interactions/. But the transaction logs kept growing.

Usually, I use larger disks and I never ran into that issue before. I think I might be overlooking something obvious. How can I effectively limit the amount of dis space used for transaction logs?

Comment: When you start Neo4j, in the `debug.log` you should see lines with the active configuration. Do you see a line for `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy` ? Its value is the one your configure ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the debug logs at startup. I will try again with `bms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=10 files` and with the default checkpoint setting (which should check and prune every 15 minutes).

Comment: normally it should work, but if you do a huge transaction (bigger than the threshold), yes the transaction log can be bigger. Otherwise you can also disable it by put it at false (neo4j will do the smaller tx log that he can do)

Comment: The `10 files` setting works. I think I overlooked something. Maybe I should delete the question.